# Is the following code thread safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have a class like this.

```
public abstract class HtmlObject<T>
{

    public HtmlObject() {}
    public HtmlObject(string id, string name, T value)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public abstract string Build();
}
```

With a concrete implementation that looks like this.

```
public class HtmlRadio : HtmlObject<string>
{
    private const string RadioHtml = "<input type='radio' name='{0}' value='{1}' {2} />{1}<br />";

    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public override string Build()
    {
        if (this.Checked) 
            return string.Format(HtmlRadio.RadioHtml, this.Name, this.Value, "checked='checked'");
        else
            return string.Format(HtmlRadio.RadioHtml, this.Name, this.Value, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

And what I want to know is if the call to `Build()` would be safe if made across threads. My assumption is it wouldn't because if I take the following series of calls

```
HtmlRadio radio = new HtmlRadio();
radio.Checked = false;
//Something could happen here?
string result = radio.Build();
```

My understanding is that the value of `radio.Checked` could change between it being set and the call to `Build()`, is this correct? If so how could I 'fix' this if I wanted to?

Comment: What exactly is it that you think "could happen here"?

Comment: You have a sequence of actions here where the order matters.  Threading is best when the order *doesnt* matter. You're going to have to do some work to make sure `Build` is only called *after* the property has been set... which is a lot like not threading it at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IHtmlRadio radio = new HtmlRadio();
radio.Checked = false;
//Something could happen here only if you give `radio` to another thread somehow.
string result = radio.Build();
```

Is another thread able to access `radio`?  If not, then you are fine.

In addition, what are you afraid of?  If checked changes from false to true or true to false, do you really care?  It's not going to blow up - it will return a boolean, not throw an exception.

**Edit:**  No, it is not thread-safe as written, another thread could change `Checked` and `Value` and `Name`, none of which are protected in any way in any order.

Comment: I guess I'm going on the assumption that my instance of this object is globally declared across a number of threads. PS: I probably dont care and I dont see a great reason to do this, I have purely asked because its something that peaked my interest and I couldn't answer.

Comment: @Maxim but that is not what you show in your example, where it appears that radio is defined locally and is only accessed by the same thread.

Answer (score 2):

In general, instance members are *not* designed to be thread-safe. Your code is as unsafe as the majority of classes in the .NET Framework.

Unless your class is designed specifically for concurrency-related scenarios (such as the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace), you should not worry about making it thread-safe; this would only result in an overly complex and inefficient implementation. Synchronization of threaded access, where applicable, should be the responsibility of the consuming code.